# Mock extension methods as an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq, mstest

Its already researched about it and found several interesting links [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq).
**But to my problem, they have not helped me.**

## Code

**I have the following interface**

```
public interface IViewFolderReference
{
    string FolderName { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension**

```
public static ICollection<TFile> GetFiles<TFile>(this IViewFolderReference view)
    where TFile: class, IFile
{
    var folder = view.GetFolder();
    return folder.Exists ? 
        Mapper.Map<ICollection<TFile>>(folder.GetFiles())
        : null;
}
```

**Concret class**

```
public class ProcessoViewModel : IViewFolderReference
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<File> Arquivos { get; set; }    
    ...
}
```

**Test method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Ao_salvar_processo_adicionar_dois_itens()
{
    // Arrange
    var vm = new Mock<ProcessoViewModel>();
    vm.Object.Arquivos = new List<File>() {
        new File { FileName = "Arquivo 1.jpg", DisplayName = "Arquivo 1" }
        ,new File { FileName = "Arquivo 2.doc", DisplayName = "Arquivo 2" }
    };

    //Act
    controller.salvar(vm.Object); // Problem here!! (GetFiles is called, How can mock the result??)

    //Assert
    var processoDb = repositorio.Query<Processo>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Imovel == vm.Object.Imovel && vm.Object.DataEntrada == p.DataEntrada);
    Assert.IsNotNull(processoDb.Arquivos);
    Assert.AreEqual(processoDb.Arquivos.Count, 2);
}
```

Comment: See Test method   ->>   // Problem here!! (GetFiles is called, How can mock the result??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS 2010, you can use [Moles](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22c07bda-ffc9-479a-9766-bfd6ccacabd4&ei=jV9wUPu6H4mQ9QTW2IHABw&usg=AFQjCNE5vIkcyAjEkCYxdKI5vV7AM3WTVw&sig2=HbEFfKcSyBrndfoCFHWXkg&cad=rja) to mock extension methods (as they are simply static methods with the first parameter using this). One example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/c56c3cc2-98d4-4e91-bd8b-e79b0813b07f). In VS 2012, you can use [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

Comment: I do not know Moles, I will study it.
It has the same goal of Moq?

Comment: Not exactly. Moq is meant to be used as a simple way to setup mocks for virtual/abstract methods. Moles goes the extra mile, allowing you to mock static classes, methods and other sort of cool stuff.

Comment: Microsoft Fakes only avaliable on VS2012 Ultimate... but its the solution thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really need to mock is `view.GetFolder()` with a suitable interface that lets you mock `folder.GetFiles()`.  This way the extension method GetFiles gets executed, but is ultimately mocked by the underlying interface implementation.  This is in line with how the mocking should be working.  If you already have a test for the GetFiles extension method, there is no harm in calling it during a test for something else.

Comment: The `GetFolder` method access `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyAppConfig + "Folder"]` and creates directory using the `DirectoryInfo` class.  

**I wish it did not.**   
An error occurs when trying to access the web.config (`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyAppConfig + "Folder"]`) in method `GetFolder`