# Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, expression, moq

I have an api service that calls another api service. When I set up the Mock objects, it failed with an error:

> NotSupportedException: expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object.

This is the code:

```
private Mock<IEnumerable<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>> _mockCarrierService;
private Mock<IApiService<AccountSearchModel>> _mockApiService;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
  _mockApiService = new Mock<IApiService<AccountSearchModel>>();
  _mockCarrierService = new Mock<IEnumerable<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>>();
  _mockApiService.Setup(x => x.GetFromApiWithQuery(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(ApiValue());

  // Error occurred when call _mockApiService.GetFromApiWithQuery() in .Select()
  _mockCarrierService.Setup(x => x
            .Select(s => s
                .GetFromApiWithQuery(It.IsAny<string>())).ToList())
                .Returns(new List<IQueryable<AccountSearchModel>> { ApiValue() });
}
```

I read [Expression testing with Moq](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2008/11/testing-expressions-with-moq.html) but it didn't work for my case. If I remove this `_mockCarrierService.Setup()`, the test case can run but fails with a `NullReferenceException` because it didn't have a valid `List<IQueryable<AccountSearchModel>>` set up.

**Any idea how I can achieve this?**

---

*Footnote: Current Solution*

FWIW, here's the solution that I currently use. *I am all ears for a better approach to the issue* (until Moq starts supporting mocking extension methods).

```
private List<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>> _mockCarrierService;
private AccountSearchController _mockController;
private Mock<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>> _mockApiService;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
   _mockApiService = new Mock<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>();
   _carrierServiceMocks = new List<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>> { _mockApiService.Object };
   _mockApiService.Setup(x => x.GetFromApiWithQuery(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(ApiValue());
   _mockController = new AccountSearchController(_carrierServiceMocks);
}
```

---

*Footnote: alternative mocking framework*

I've also found a commercial mocking framework that supports mocking extension method and link to the how-to docs: [Telerik JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/advanced-usage-extension-methods-mocking.html).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This problem occurs because you are trying to mock `Select` method, which is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx), not an instance method of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Basically, there is no way to mock an extension method. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq) for some ideas that you may find useful.

UPD (12/11/2014):

To gain more understanding on mocking extension methods, think about the following:

- Although extension methods are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type, they are actually just a static methods with a bit of syntactic sugar.
- Extension methods from `System.Linq` namespace are implemented as [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) — they are  deterministic and they don't have any observable [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). I agree that [static methods are evil, except those that are pure functions](http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters) — hope you would agree with this statement too :)
- So, given an object of type `T`, how would you implement static pure function `f(T obj)`? It is only possible by combining other pure functions that are defined for object `T` (or any other pure functions, actually), or by reading immutable and deterministic global state (to keep function `f` deterministic and side-effect-free). Actually, "immutable and deterministic global state" has more convenient name — a constant.

So, it turns out that if you follow the rule that static methods should be pure functions (and it looks like Microsoft follows this rule, at least for the LINQ methods), mocking an extension method `f(this T obj)` *should be reducible to mocking non-static methods or state used by that extension method* — simply because that extension method relies on the `obj` instance methods and state in its implementation (and possibly on the other pure functions and/or constant values).

In case of `IEnumerable<T>`, `Select()` extension method is [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d3e6cf8553f8ad92) in terms of `foreach` statement which, in turn, uses `GetEnumerator()` method. So you can mock `GetEnumerator()` and achieve required behavior for extension methods that rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found another article from the same author of the one that you mentioned here. It might work if I add more complicate [Fact] method to it. I have to try to know for sure.

Comment: @IsabelHM, I updated the answer, so you might think about the problem from a different perspective :)

Answer (score 8):

You have:

```
_mockCarrierService = new Mock<IEnumerable<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>>();
```

So you mock `IEnumerable<>`. The only member `IEnumerable<>` has is a method `GetEnumerator()` (plus another method with the same signature `GetEnumerator()` inherited from the base interface). The `Select` method is really an extension method (as was pointed out in the first answer) which is a static method that works by calling `GetEnumerator()` (possibly through C# `foreach` statement).

It is possible to make things work by doing `Setup` of `GetEnumerator` on your mock.

However, it is much simpler to simply use a concrete, non-mock type which "is" `IEnumerable<>`, such as `List<>`. So try:

```
_mockCarrierService = new List<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>();
```

Then add an entry to the `List<>`. What you should add, is a `Mock<ICarrierApiService<AccountSearchModel>>` on which `GetFromApiWithQuery` Method is setup.

Comment: yes, that's what I realized after reading the article @Sergey mentioned in his answer. I have to try to know for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

also if u need to Mock IConfiguration u can use this code below:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "your-key", "your value" }
        });
        var config = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question about mocking `IConfiguration` is referring this answer as duplicate, I will contribute my dime here.
This is how I "Mock" `IConfiguration`, which is, in my opinion, a bit cleaner:

```
    private static IConfiguration GetConfigurationMock(string jsonConfiguration)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonConfiguration);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        var conf = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        conf.AddJsonStream(stream);
        var confRoor = conf.Build();

        return confRoor; 
    }
```

Original question: [How to setup Mock of IConfigurationRoot to return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618686/how-to-setup-mock-of-iconfigurationroot-to-return-value)