# Unit testing in Windows phone/store apps

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I am working on a Windows Phone/Store and a Windows 10 UWP app. I am trying to understand what are some good techniques to unit test.

I have the unit test project setup and i have written a few unit tests. I am using CaliburnMicro framework and i have setup constructor injection which in turn helps me in unit testing as i have interfaces defined.

Is it a good practice to test Internal APIs? For example, say i have a service that checks for NetworkInfomation and gives me appropriate results or a battery check service? Would be good to test these?

Also, i use Background Transfer Service and background Task as well. Would it be feasible to test the upload scenarios ?

New to unit testing, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use Caliburn.Micro in my code but I don't think it should matter most MVVM frameworks work the same. I use [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) for my a mocking framework which works really well with dependency injection.

Problems with Moq is in conjunction with Caliburn is that Caliburn uses a lot of extension functions which is difficult to impossible to [Verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)

Abstract as far as possible and [avoid testing implementation details](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2011/10/06/avoid-testing-implementation-details-test-behaviours/), in short test behavior and make an abstraction of implementation detail such as NetworkInfomation and Background Transfer Service.

```
public class GolldysNetworkInfomation : INetworkInfomation
{
   NetworkInfomation networkInformation;
}

public class SystemUnderTest
{
    public SystemUnderTest(INetworkInfomation networkInfomation)
    {
    }
}
```

You can now use `INetworkInfomation` to simulate your `NetworkInfomation` during unit testing, and allows you to create other implementations of the `INetworkInfomation`.

There are two schools of thought about unit testing:

1. Classical
2. Mockist

You can look at [Classical vs Mockist](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/classical-vs-mockist-testing/) approach to better understand.

Hope this helps.