# Mock GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have private property to access AuthenticationManager:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager => HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

I want to mock the method GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() in order to receive fake ExternalLoginInfo object:

```
ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Both GetOwinContext() and GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() methods are extension methods. Is it possible to see source code of these methods to see how they works?

Comment: If you want to mock GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(), why do you care about it source code and how it works? And in general, you don't have easy way to mock extension method. Check this (Moq specific) for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq

Comment: If you want to mock  Extension or static methods then you need to use licensed libraries such as TypeMock or RhinoMock ..  Moq doesn't support this.

Comment: I want to try mocking objects that are used inside these extension methods to change behaviour of these methods, but without source code I don't know what they are using and how.

Answer (score 3):

> Both GetOwinContext() and GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() methods are extension methods. Is it possible to see source code of these methods to see how they works?

Sure, one way is to use ILSpy.  For example:

```
/// <summary>
///     Extracts login info out of an external identity
/// </summary>
/// <param name="manager"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(this IAuthenticationManager manager)
{
    if (manager == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
    }
    return AuthenticationManagerExtensions.GetExternalLoginInfo(await TaskExtensions.WithCurrentCulture<AuthenticateResult>(manager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie")));
}
```

However, in my opinion this is just a Rabbit hole.  Instead, you should be using Dependency Injection to inject a `IAuthenticationManager` into your controller.  Then you can simply Mock it and the methods you need instead of testing internal *microsoft* code.

Comment: I was able to mock the extension response using `IAuthenticationManager` and mocking the following: `GetMock<IAuthenticationManager>().Setup(x => x.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie")).Returns(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticateResult(null, new AuthenticationProperties(), new AuthenticationDescription())));`