# Mock HttpContext GetTokenAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, xunit, httpcontext

how can I mock the HttpContext GetTokenAsync to return a string?

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

I tried this based on what I found on the internet :

```
var authenticationServiceStub = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();

authenticationServiceStub 
    .Setup(x => x.GetTokenAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync("value");
```

I can select "x.GetTokenAsync" but I get the message :

```
IAuthenticationService does not contain a definition for 'GetTokenAsync'...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61631313/1875256

Comment: Does `IAuthenticationService` have a method `GetTokenAsync` , that takes a `string` argument and returns a `Task<string>`?