# When mocking HttpContext, SignOutAsync fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, httpcontext

I'm using `SignOutAsync` from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.

In my unit tests, I get an `ArgumentNullException` somewhere within that extension method, which says

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

```
  Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

  Stack Trace: 
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
AccountController.SignOut() line 123
AccountControllerTests.MyUnitTest() line 456
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I'm not directly providing 'provider', so I assume the extension method is building it from the HttpContext.

The HttpContext in my tests is created using Moq:

```
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
```

Is there a way I can coax my mock into providing a value for 'provider'?  Do I need to switch to a DefaultHttpContext, and provide a value for `ServiceScopeFactory`?  (Tricky, because DefaultHttpContext isn't mock-able.)

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace of where the `ArgumentNullException` was being thrown from - there's _a lot_ of possible control-paths through `SignOutAsync` so we need to narrow it down...

Comment: @Dai, thanks, done

Comment: Looks like you need to set-up a _real_ (not fake) `IHost` and `IServiceProvider` (from `ConfigureServices`) IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6699b0548c825e8acaa3594f96c3cb2a161f19df/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L216C30-L216C30), `SignOutAsync` will eventually try to call a private method `GetAuthenticationService`, and that tries to call `context.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthenticationService>()`.

The generic `GetService` is an extension method, so your null `provider` really is `RequestServices`. `RequestServices` is abstract on `HttpContext`, so it will be implemented by Moq, and by default on a loose mock, that will simply return null. Oops, there's your crash.

So, could set it up:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = /*...*/;

httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.RequestServices).Returns(serviceProvider);
```

But by then you could just use a `DefaultHttpContext` and *set* the provider:

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
{
    RequestServices = serviceProvider
};
```

And now all you need is a service provider. For that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336489/moq-iserviceprovider-iservicescope) (you can mock one, or create one from a `ServiceCollection`, up to you).