# Mock session object with custom extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, session, mocking, asp.net-core-mvc

In my asp.net core 2 application, I have a static class which handles some interactions with the session. For example :

```
public static class BookManager
{
    private const string Key = "Books";
    public static HttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor => new HttpContextAccessor();

    public static void AddBooksToContainer(IEnumerable<BookViewModel> books)
    {
        ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set(Key, books);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<BookViewModel> GetBooks()
    {
        return ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>(Key);
    }
}
```

I have also added some extension methods to the session object :

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, IEnumerable<T> value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) :
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Update: This is how i try to mock :

```
         var bookList = new List<BookViewModel>()
        {
            new BookViewModel {Author = "test", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), InStock = 1, Price = 1000, Title = "tes"}
        };

        var httpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().SetupAllProperties();
        httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>("test")).Returns(bookList);
```

And the error i get :

```
System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: x => 
x.HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable`1>("test")
```

The problem is I have tried many ways to mock session and its extension methods but I got no result yet. many ways work in .netframework and not core.

I use xunit for testing and Moq library to mock the objects. Please tell me how can I mock session and its extension methods. Appreciate it.

Comment: Depend on abstractions and not concretions. Create a Factory method that will provide you with the `IHttpContextAccessor` abstraction. This will allow you to replace the abstraction when testing with a mock.

Comment: Show how you have tried to test it so far.

Comment: @Nkosi , I updated the post with the piece of code which shows how i try to mock but it gives me this error :  
System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: x => x.HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable`1>("test")

Comment: You can't mock the extension methods. You can however mock the body of the extension method. Provided they are not extension methods themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to .NET Core, is a limitation of the mocking library, you can't mock extension methods with Moq.

This might help: [Mocking Extension Methods with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)

Answer (score 1):

Depend on abstractions and not concretions. Create a Factory method that will provide you with the `IHttpContextAccessor` abstraction.

```
public static class BookManager {
    private const string Key = "Books";
    public static Func<IHttpContextAccessor> ContextAccessor = () => new HttpContextAccessor();

    public static void AddBooksToContainer(IEnumerable<BookViewModel> books) {
        ContextAccessor().HttpContext.Session.Set(Key, books);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<BookViewModel> GetBooks() {
        return ContextAccessor().HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>(Key);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to replace the abstraction when testing with a mock.

```
//Arrange
var mock = mock.Of<IHttpContextAccessor>();
BookManager.ContextAccessor = () => {
    return mock.Object;
};

//...
```

Better yet if this manager only has need of the session then do not expose more than it needs.

```
public static class BookManager {
    private const string Key = "Books";
    public static Func<ISession> Session = () => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext.Session;

    public static void AddBooksToContainer(IEnumerable<BookViewModel> books) {
        Session().Set(Key, books);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<BookViewModel> GetBooks() {
        return Session().Get<IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>(Key);
    }
}
```

So now only the explicit dependencies need to be mocked for tests.

According to [ISession Extensions source code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/SessionExtensions.cs#L32) `GetString` and `SetString` are also extension methods

You will need to mock [`ISession.TryGetValue`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/85402d4bd6a64bc216bab1ff50d9b19a4f97db79/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/ISession.cs#L46) and [`ISession.Set`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/85402d4bd6a64bc216bab1ff50d9b19a4f97db79/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/ISession.cs#L54)

```
//Arrange
var mock = Mock.Of<ISession>();
BookManager.Session = () => {
    return mock;
};

var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[{some books json strings here}]");

Mock.Get(mock).Setup(_ => _.TryGetValue("Books", out value))
    .Returns(true);

//Act
var books = BookManager.GetBooks();

//...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only problem is in last part ( setup ). I get  Invalid setup on an extension method: _ => _.GetString("Books") . and as you said we can not mock extension methods. Is there any way to fix this part?

Comment: @peymangilmour that that means that `GertString` is also an extension method. You would need to find the source code of that method and see what it uses so you know what to mock.

Comment: @peymangilmour they are in fact extension methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Extension_Methods