# Unit Test: SetUp HtpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync returns error: Unsupported expression Exception GetTokenAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to Unit Test the code below.

```
    public async Task<AppErrorCountByDateListVm> GetAppErrorCountByDateAsync()
    {
       var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            if (accessToken != null)
            {
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            }  
...
```

Specially I want to moq / set up: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync

Below is my Unit Test:

```
        private IErrorLogService _sut;

        private Mock<HttpClient> _httpClient;
        private Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> _httpContextAccessor;
        private Mock<IJsonSerializerUtility> _jsonSerializerUtility;

        [SetUp]
        public void RunBeforeEachTest()
        {
            _httpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
            _httpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            _jsonSerializerUtility = new Mock<IJsonSerializerUtility>();

            _sut = new ErrorLogService(_httpClient.Object, _httpContextAccessor.Object, _jsonSerializerUtility.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task OnInitializedAsyncTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            _httpContextAccessor.Setup(h => h.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")).ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<string>());

            //Act
            await _sut.GetAppErrorCountByDateAsync();

            //Assert
        }
```

I am getting the following error messages:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....GetTokenAsync("access_token")
Extension methods (here: AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.GetTokenAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

I assume I am missing a few steps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error you getting is because you are trying to mock a static method (extension method). And you can't do that, at least not with the framework you are using.

I have faced the same problem, and I just wrapped it up. Let me explain...
Create a wrapper object on HttpContext, with that you'll be able to mock "GetTokenAsync".

See this [Memoires of a http request - How I got unit tested](https://www.sweetmustard.be/nl/blog/how-i-got-unit-tested), it has a good example of this exact problem.

Of course, there are other ways to mock Static methods, have a look at [Mocking Extension Methods with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I got away from this issue for a little while but I am back on it.  For some reason the original code that I wanted to unit test did not copy over correctly so I updated that section. I spent sometime trying some of your ideas but I don't get it.  I don't understand how can  wrap up  HttpContext when it is a property off of HttpContextAccessor.  Sorry that I am being a little thick. I just don't get it.  Can you give me some more hints.  Thanks @Yassine