# How to mock IAppCache's GetOrAddAsync method with It.IsAny AddItemFactory function

Tags: c#, testing, moq

The method I'm testing has this bit of code in it:

```
var devices = await _cache.GetOrAddAsync(_cacheKey, AddItemFactory, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(Configuration.DeviceInMinutes));`
```

Where `_cache` is an `IAppCache` and is being mocked with a `new Mock<IAppCache>();` in the test

AddItemFactory has the following signature:

```
private async Task<IDictionary<int, Device>> AddItemFactory()
```

In my test I have written:

```
        _appCache.Setup(x => x.GetOrAddAsync(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<Task<IDictionary<int, Device>>>>(),
            It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>())
        ).ReturnsAsync(fakeDictionary);
```

When that .Setup gets evaluated, my test crashes with the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: x => x.GetOrAddAsync<IDictionary<int, Device>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<IDictionary<int, Device>>>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>())
```

I think it's mocked correctly because Visual Studio intellisense isn't complaining and signatures being wrong but I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: What's the signature of `IAppCache.GetOrAddAsync`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking Extension Methods with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)

Comment: @mm8 it's what I have in the _appCache.Setup. (string, Func<Task<T>>, DateTimeOffset)

Comment: @RoboKozo: You need to provide more details if you want any help. Your issue is not reproducible based on the information in your question.

Comment: Hmm... well I can also inform that the app is using https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That GetOrAddAsync method overload is an extension method; extension methods cannot be mocked.

```
GetOrAddAsync<T>(
      this IAppCache cache,
      string key,
      Func<Task<T>> addItemFactory,
      DateTimeOffset expires)
```

You need to mock the following method on the `IAppCache` interface:

```
Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(string key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>> addItemFactory);
```

If you want to use Moq to do this, the library [LazyCache.Testing.Moq](https://github.com/rgvlee/LazyCache.Testing) (disclaimer - I am the author) implements this via the following setup:

```
cachingServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetOrAddAsync(
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>>>()))    
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(cacheEntryValue));
```

where `cacheEntryValue` is the task result value an invocation should return.

If you don't need to use Moq, given you are using a GetOrAdd* method, you should be able to use the built-in fake (`MockCachingService`) provided by the LazyCache library as per the [doco](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/wiki/Unit-testing-code-using-LazyCache).

Comment: I tested this out to see if it worked and it did! Thank you! FWIW I ended up just using a 'real' cache in my test: new LazyCache.CachingService();

Comment: I use GetAsync<string>(key) from this package and the response time gets more than 20 ms. how can i fix this? @rgvlee

Comment: Which package, LazyCache.Testing.Moq?