# Verify the sequence of execution of methods in Xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net, method-chaining

I have to write the test case to verify the sequence of execution of chained methods.
suppose I have written code as shown below

```
 _store 
     .SetInput(input1)
     .Method1()
     .Method2()
     .Method3();
```

How can I write a test case to check SetInput executed first, method1 executed second, and so on?
If someone changes the actual implementation or order of method chaining then the test case should fail.
I know that I can't mock the extension method then what is the best way to write the test case to check the sequence of execution of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that your `_store` implements the following interface:

```cs
public interface IStore
{
    IStore SetInput(string input);
    IStore Method1();
    IStore Method2();
    IStore Method3();
}
```

For the sake of simplicity here is class that makes use of an `IStore` implementation:

```cs
public class SystemUnderTest
{
    private readonly IStore _store;
    public SystemUnderTest(IStore store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    public void MyAction()
    {
        _store
            .SetInput("input1")
            .Method1()
            .Method2()
            .Method3();
    }
}
```

So, in order to make sure that the actions are executing in this particular order we can make use of the `MockSequence` ([ref](https://documentation.help/Moq/DFF22AE2.htm)). Here is a sample unit test for this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void GivenAFlawlessStore_WhenICallMyAction_ThenItCallsTheMethodsOfTheStoreInAParticularOrder()
{
    //Arrange
    var storeMock = new Mock<IStore>();
    var expectedSequence = new MockSequence();
    storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.SetInput(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(storeMock.Object);
    storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method1())
        .Returns(storeMock.Object);
    storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method2())
        .Returns(storeMock.Object);
    storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method3())
        .Returns(storeMock.Object);

    var SUT = new SystemUnderTest(storeMock.Object);

    //Act 
    SUT.MyAction();

    //Assert
    storeMock.Verify(store => store.SetInput("input1"), Times.Once);
}
```

If you change the order either in the unit test or inside the `MyAction` method it will fail with a `NullReferenceException`, because it can't call the next method on a null.

Change the order inside the `MyAction`

```cs
public void MyAction()
{
    _store
        .SetInput("input1")
        .Method2()
        .Method1() //NullReferenceException
        .Method3();
}
```

Change the order of the `MockSequence`

```cs
//Arrange
var storeMock = new Mock<IStore>();
var expectedSequence = new MockSequence();
storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.SetInput(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(storeMock.Object);
storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method1())
    .Returns(storeMock.Object);
storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method3())
    .Returns(storeMock.Object);
storeMock.InSequence(expectedSequence).Setup(x => x.Method2())
.Returns(storeMock.Object);
```

In order words your `Setup` calls won't have any effect in advance. When you call the `SetInput` from the `MyAction` the first setup will be executed in the sequence.
If you try to call `Method2` before `Method1`'s `Setup` call then it will fail.

Comment: This works only if methods are in the interface but in my case
    SetInput("input1"),Method1(), Method2(), Method3() are extension methods and i can't write this in the setup  like this Setup(x => x.Method1())

Comment: @PavanAmbhure You can't directly mock extension methods because they are `static`. [Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)