# Mocking an Extention method C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, caching, redis, moq

so I'm trying to Mock (Redis) `IDistributedCache.GetStringAsync` and `IDistributedCache.SetStringAsync`, but I understand we won't be able to Mock extension methods, however, we can mock the methods used by those extension methods to achieve our testing but sadly, I couldn't find what are the methods that have been used by `GetStringAsync`/`SetStringAsync` even in official docs, so I'd appreciate if someone could help me out here, on how to mock `SetStringAsync` and `GetStringAsync`, I've added my current test cases below

Edit: When I run the current test case I'm getting the below error

> Unsupported expression: x => x.GetStringAsync(key, CancellationToken)
> Extension methods (here: DistributedCacheExtensions.GetStringAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

```cs
public async Task Set_Records_with_key()
{
    // Arrange
    var key = "key";
    var value = "cdc";
    var cache = _builder.DistributedCache;

    var sut = _builder.Build();

    // Act
    await sut.GetRecordAsync<string>(key);

    // Assert
    cache.Verify(x => x.SetStringAsync(key, value,default));
}


public async Task GetRecords_with_key()
{
    // Arrange
    var key = "key";
    var cache = _builder.DistributedCache;

    var sut = _builder.Build();

    // Act
    await sut.GetRecordAsync<string>(key);

    // Assert
    cache.Verify(x => x.GetStringAsync(key, default));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq

Comment: from where you get the interface `IDistributedCache` and from where you get the extension method? What nuget packages you are using for this?