How to mock TaskOrchestrationContext.CallHttpAsync to test an Azure Function .net isolated method
I have this Azure Function orchestrator
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Functions.Triggers.Orchestration.StudentEnrollments
{
    public class SimpleOrchestrator
    {
        [Function("O_Simple")]
        public async Task<bool> RunAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ctx)
        {
            var aTest = await ctx.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=linux"));

            if (aTest.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}

And this test
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Moq;
using Functions.Triggers.Orchestration.StudentEnrollments;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace tests.UnitTests
{
    public class SimpleTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task Test_SimpleTestOrchestrator()
        {
            var test = new SimpleOrchestrator();
            var mockContext = new Mock<TaskOrchestrationContext>();
            mockContext
                .Setup(x => x.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=linux"), null, null))
                .ReturnsAsync(new DurableHttpResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK));
            var sut = await test.RunAsync(mockContext.Object);
            Assert.True(sut);
        }
    }
}

I get the error

System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, ltiUserGetUrl, null, null) Extension methods (here: TaskOrchestrationContextExtensionMethods.CallHttpAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

This is how I was able to mock CallHttpAsync for the in process model but I can't seem to find out how to do it for .net isolated.

"Extension methods [...] may not be used in setup / verification expressions" See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295960/126014

Thanks Mark. I thought there would be an easier way to test as using CallHttpAsync is recommended instead of calling Activity methods.  I guess that would be on the Azure Functions SDK to provide better support for mocking, and not on Moq.  I'll dig into that question more.

Below code worked for me:
Fuction1.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace RithFunc1
{
    public class rifun
    {
        [Function(nameof(rifun))]
        public static async Task<bool> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ricxt)
        {
            ILogger ri_lg = ricxt.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(rifun));
            ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Mock Started !!!");
            var ri_tst = await ricxt.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=linux"));
            if (ri_tst.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Mock is Successfull !!!");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        [Function("Test_fun")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient ric,
            FunctionContext ec)
        {
            ILogger logger = ec.GetLogger("Test_fun");
            string r_id = await ric.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(rifun));
            logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", r_id);
            return await ric.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, r_id);
        }
    }
    public class RithTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task Rith_testing()
        {
            var r_moc_cxt = new Mock<TaskOrchestrationContext>();
            r_moc_cxt
                .Setup(rith => rith.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=linux"), null, null))
                .ReturnsAsync(new DurableHttpResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK));
            var ri = await rifun.RunOrchestrator(r_moc_cxt.Object);
            Assert.True(ri);
        }
    }
}

Output:


Does your test work?  Your output shows the HttpTrigger working, but this question is asking about the mocking of CallHttpAsync

Yes, it worked, If test returned true then the log statement executed.

Ok, I'll run it.  But if I look at your code the log statement will execute if you run the orchestrator via the HttpTrigger - so you can get that output without actually running the test.

Yes - even the log in your screenshot shows you're getting that output as a result of using the HttpTrigger.

Try and test it once, I think it will work

Same error:
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: rith => rith.CallHttpAsync(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=linux"), null, null) Extension methods (here: TaskOrchestrationContextExtensionMethods.CallHttpAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Have you copy pasted my code fully? I woul suggest you to create a new one and then test

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

        var mockContext = new Mock<TaskOrchestrationContext>();
    mockContext
        .Setup(r => r.CallActivityAsync<DurableHttpResponse>(It.IsAny<TaskName>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<TaskOptions>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new DurableHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = $"{{ \"hasRestrictions\": {hasRestrictions} }}"
        });

Mocking CallActivityAsync currently works.
