# How can I mock or similarly inject a replacement for the query extension method applied to an NHibernate Session

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, extension-methods, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to mock out or similar the Query extension method applied to an nhibernate-3 session. Similar to the following...

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities
{
  return entities = Session.Query<Entity>();
}
```

Where the Query extension method returns an IQueryable collection.

I can clearly mock out the Session object by using Moq or Rhinos. But as of yet not found a suitable way to fake out or replace the extension method. In fact reading answers to several questions on stack overflow, it may not be possible.

see questions 
[How to mock extension methods with Rhino Mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988243/how-to-mock-extension-methods-with-rhino-mock)
[Mocking Extension Methods with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq)
and links within..

I came across the [microsoft moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) project and thought maybe I could use that to create a subsitute assembly by which I could test this one particular method. Using Pex its relatively quite easy to generate such an assembly however when I try to work a way of using this Assembly its not immediately clear of a way to factor this out.

Ideally I would like to just check to make sure that the query extension method is called by this method and a pre-empted result is returned..

Has anyone done anything similar, would like to hear peoples thoughts..

Ps. there is type mock but I don't have the funds to buy it :)

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are static methods. So you can't use a mocking library like Rhino Mocks or Moq. (This is a CLR limitation.) TypeMock or Moles get around the limitation by wedging themselves in at the profiler level. (They register themselves as a profiler and inject code into your app domain.)

You can just define your own extension method with the same signature as found in NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED!!!
public static class MockedSessionExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(this ISession session) {
        // your mocked impl goes here
    }
}
```

The problem with this is it has to be in your production code with some conditional compilation directives around it.

Personally I integration test my repositories against a local database or an in-memory database like SQLite. I then mock out my repositories when testing higher level components. I wouldn't recommend mocking out ISession, ISessionFactory, and the like.

Comment: James, I agree with you, and I do use integration tests to test the repository layers. I use sqlite to do the checking of the mappings and sql server for repositories. I was interested if someone had found a way to do this via unit testing thats all.

Comment: My question to you is what would you gain from unit testing your repositories? If you feel it's worth the effort, create an IGenericRepository<T> (or something similar) that encapsulates the session and mock that.

Comment: That is pretty much what I have done. But of course I got to a point with the Query extension method and hence the question. 

Answering what would I gain from unit testing the repository, 
I think it is important especially with a fundamental part of your application to test this where possible without relying on any external components or dependencies. I think its useful to test any data specific code that enhances nhibernate or uses it.

Comment: Whilst this is an interesting answer, it does not answer the actual question.