# Weird error using Rhino Mocks "type doesn't match the return value"

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

EDIT: I played with this example and now [my question is a different one entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661979/stubbing-a-static-extension-method-seems-to-work-in-rhino-mocks-unless-i-cast-th).

When I run this example:

```
using Rhino.Mocks;

public interface IInterface
{
    decimal GetDecimal();
}

static class Util
{
    public static double? DecToDouble(this IInterface input)
    {
        return (double) input.GetDecimal();
    }
}

class MockExample
{
    public void RunThis()
    {
        var stubReader = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IInterface>();
        stubReader.Stub(sr => sr.DecToDouble()).Return(1.2);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Type 'System.Double' doesn't match the return type 'System.Decimal' for method 'IInterface.GetDecimal();'

Why?

Comment: Did you build in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: OK, this seems to be a custom configuration. Is optimization enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhino Mocks can only intercept calls that are made through the stubbed interface. The extension method above is compiled to something like:

```
Util.DecToDouble(sr)
```

This means that your setup/return basically reads like this:

```
stubReader.Stub(sr => Util.DecToDouble(sr)).Return(1.2);
```

That clearly is not going to work (with most mocking frameworks). The proper way to achieve what you want is:

```
stubReader.Stub(sr => sr.GetDecimal())).Return(1.2);
```

***After further investigation:***
Rhino Mocks internally connects the method declared by Stub() to the value declared by Return() by invoking the delegate passed to Stub() and saving the last applied method invocation. This saved method invocation is afterwards connected to the return value. When doing this Rhino Mocks internally checks whether the return type of the saved invocation matches the type of the value. If they don't match Rhino Mocks raises the exception you are seeing. The correct way to define the stubbing would be

```
    decimal val = 1.2M;
    stubReader.Stub(sr => sr.DecToDouble()).Return(val);
```

But this does not compile, because the generic type params of Stub() and Return() must be compatible. So really the only way to define the stubbing is to ignore the extension methods and only stub the methods defined in the interface.

Comment: I will try that, definitely. But check out the edits I just made. The static method stub is working if I don't convert the type within the method. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to mock `IInterface` then you're stubbing the wrong method:

```
public void RunThis()
{
    var stubReader = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IInterface>();
    stubReader.Stub(sr => sr.GetDecimal()).Return(1.2);
}
```

If you're trying to stub `DecToDouble`, you can't with RhinoMocks.  Extension methods are compiled to static method calls which can't be mocked by RhinoMocks because they're bound at compile-time.  Some stub frameworks use low-level profiler calls to intercept static calls but RhinoMocks does not have that capability that I know of.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988243/how-to-mock-extension-methods-with-rhino-mock) for a similar discussion.

Comment: But `DecToDouble` is a valid extension method for `IInterface`, right?

Comment: Extension methods are really just static methods, which you can't stub.  They are bound at compile-time.