# Stubbing a static extension method seems to work in Rhino Mocks unless I cast the return variable. Why?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am able to stub a static extension method using Rhino Mocks but if I cast the return value to another type, I get an error. Why?

```
using Rhino.Mocks;

public interface INumberGenerator
{
    double GetDouble();
}

static class NumberGeneratorExtensionMethods
{
    public static double GetTheDouble(this INumberGenerator input)
    {
        return input.GetDouble();
    }

    public static decimal GetTheDoubleCastToDecimal(this INumberGenerator input)
    {
        return (decimal) input.GetDouble();
    }
}

class MockExample
{
    public void TriggerTheError()
    {
        var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<INumberGenerator>();

        // This works
        stub.Stub(obj => obj.GetTheDouble()).Return(1.2d);

        // This throws the error
        stub.Stub(obj => obj.GetTheDoubleCastToDecimal()).Return(1.2m);
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Type 'System.Decimal' doesn't match the return type 'System.Double' for method 'INumberGenerator.GetDouble();'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Warning: this is really a suspicion more than anything else**

The problem is that you're not *really* stubbing the extension methods at all - you're stubbing `GetDouble` in both cases.

I haven't looked at the code for Rhino Mocks for a while, but I *suspect* that the `Stub` method is basically saying:

- Get ready for some calls on the mock!
- Call the delegate passed in as an argument
- Note which calls were made

That means you're effectively doing this:

```
canGetDecimal.Stub(ng => ng.GetDouble()).Return(1.2d);
canGetDecimal.Stub(ng => (decimal) ng.GetDouble()).Return(1.2m);
```

At that point, it would notice that you called `GetDouble` - but then you're trying to set the return value to 1.2m, which is invalid.

You could validate this pretty easily, with some logging. Add a log line to `GetTheDoubleCastToDecimal` and then split out the `Stub` call from the `Return` call:

```
Console.WriteLine("Before Stub");
var stubCall = canGetDecimal.Stub(obj => obj.GetTheDoubleCastToDecimal();
Console.WriteLine("After Stub");
stubCall.Return(1.2m);
```

I strongly suspect you'll find that whatever logging you add into the extension method is still logged between "Before Stub" and "After Stub" - showing that the extension method *isn't* being mocked out.

**Moral**: don't try to mock/stub extension methods. They're not polymorphic; they're just static methods, and it would be pretty tricky to fake them without deep wizardry. Only try to fake out genuinely polymorphic operations.

Comment: Good guess: That's exactly what is happening. Also see the second part of my answer to the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17661620/31985

Comment: +1: essentially extension (static) calls are ignored and down-the-line `GetDouble` is stubbed, which causes mismatch in second call.

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility to stub extension method or any other static method without any framework. This requires a bit of additional afford.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Func<int,int, int> _doSumm = (x, y) => x + y;

    public static int Summ(this int x, int y)
    {
        return _doSumm(x, y);
    }
}
```

It allows you to substitute the implementation. You can just change value of `_doSumm` field.