# How to do test expectations in container.Resolve with arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a question regarding how to create test expectations for a unity container resolve call which has parameter overrides.

This is my function:

```
protected override Response DecodeResponse(byte[] data)
{
    Response response = base.container.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverrides
    {
        { "Code", GCommandCode.ClearAlarm }, 
        { "Error", 0 } 
    });

    return response;
}
```

And this is my unit test:

```
// Arrange
IUnityContainer container = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUnityContainer>();

container.Expect(c => c.RegisterType<MyClass>()).Repeat.Once(); 
container.Expect(c => c.Resolve<MyClass>()).Repeat.Once().Return(preparedResponse);

Mock mock = new Mock(container);

// Act
Response response = mock.DecodeResponse(new byte[] {});

// Assert
container.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

I would like to create a test expectation to test the constructor parameters because with the actual test the expectations passes no matter which arguments are used, and the resolve call returns a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what your referring to as "constructor parameters" is the container. And you want to verify the expectation of .Resolve with arguments.

You cannot "verify" an [expectation on a static extension member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923829/why-is-real-code-being-called-in-this-test-using-rhinomocks), of an IUnityContainer such as Resolve.

```
 public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, 
                            params ResolverOverride[] overrides);
```

There are other ways you can do this such as you can to abstract it out to a virtual method so you can specify the expectation.