# trying to verify my module has called registerViewWithRegion using Moq

Tags: c#, prism, moq

This is maddening. I am trying to write a simple test using Moq (at the moment but I will use anything that works) that will verify that registerViewWithRegion was called but every freaking method in prism is a static extension method! I have searched the web looking for an example of this and haven't found anything... Hopefully someone can tell me how to go about this. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var regionManagerMock = new Mock<IRegionManager>();
regionManagerMock.Setup(r => r.RegisterViewWithRegion("",  typeof(RibbonControlView)));
container.RegisterInstance(regionManagerMock.Object);

 RibbonControlModule ribbonControlModule = new RibbonControlModule(container);
 ribbonControlModule.Initialize();

 regionManagerMock.Verify(x => x.RegisterViewWithRegion("RibbonRegion", typeof(RibbonControlView)));
```

Of course that blows up cause `RegisterViewWithRegion` is a static extension method, every wanna be coding rockstar has written a howto about using tests but I can't find turd about about what to do when you run into something like this (static extension methods), I can't believe it's this hard... Or maybe I am just an idiot - that would be fine if someone could just explain how I go about doing this...

Just as a side note - I found this http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/68353?ProjectName=compositewpf - In that post they are using Rhino which I would use if it would work but it blows up as well... I don't know how that code in that post ever worked.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps this question will shed some light. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562129/how-do-i-use-moq-to-mock-an-extension-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an instance of the [IRegionViewRegistry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregionviewregistry%28PandP.38%29.aspx) instead of IRegionManager. As the [RegisterViewWithRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregionviewregistry%28PandP.38%29.aspx) method, which is used to perform View Discovery, is an instance member, you will be able to mock it as desired.

I hope this helps.
Damian

Comment: That's a great answer. I had prototyped up something with Moles, but you've got it right.