# Lambda parameter not working in Moq

Tags: moq

I keep getting the "Unsupported expression" exception. It seems that the lambda expression (a=>a.PP_EventID==1) is the problem. How do solved this one?

```
pricepackPersistenceMock.Setup(pricepack => pricepack.Delete(a=>a.PP_EventID==1)).Verifiable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the predicate inside `It.Is<T>()` method.

```
pricepackPersistenceMock.Setup(pricepack => ricepack.Delete(It.Is<TypeOfa>(a=>a.PP_EventID==1)))
                        .Verifiable();
```

**Update:**

```
eventPersistenceMock.Setup(u => u.Single(It.IsAny<Func<tbl_SBAem_Event, bool>>()))
                    .Returns(eventlists.Where(a => a.EventMngID == currentevent.EventMngID).Single());
// you can directly return the value
//verifiable is not needed because you set the return value
```

Comment: Ufuk do you know how to mock this one T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate);?

Comment: That's probably a LINQ extension method. You can take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562129/205859)

Comment: no, I create that method in the repository along with the delete method.

Comment: here is the code eventPersistenceMock.Setup(u => u.Single(It.IsAny<Func<tbl_SBAem_Event, bool>>())).Returns((Func<tbl_SBAem_Event, bool> expression) => eventlists.Where(a=>a.EventMngID==currentevent.EventMngID).Single()).Verifiable();

Comment: I think there is an error with the code becuase I will always get the first index.

Comment: What do you mean you get the first index? You are calling the Single method, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I got it already. What I mean If I try to get the value from the collection having an id=1. I will always get the id having equal 0. But I solved it already. thanks