# Mocking out a method that takes optional parameters that default to null

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, moq, nest

I am writing a unit test against a function that hits Elasticsearch through NEST.  My unit test's setup looks like this:

```
var mockResponse = new Mock<IBulkResponse>();
var mockClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
mockClient.Setup(x => x.IndexManyAsync<Store>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Store>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task<IBulkResponse>.Run(() => mockResponse.Object));
```

The `IndexManyAsync` function takes has a function signature of `Task<IBulkResponse> IndexManyAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> object, string index = null, string type = null)`.

As you can see, I tried to set up my mock `IElasticClient` to Mock out that method above, but I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.IndexManyAsync<Store>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable`1>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>())
```

It's not clear to me what is going on here.  Why am I unable to mock this method that takes optional parameters?

Comment: Is `IndexManyAsync` an extension method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this particular overload of `IndexManyAsync` [is an extension method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/4fcecae93dcf16a4ff7e110135da81eed409dda5/src/Nest/ConvenienceExtensions/IndexManyExtensions.cs#L38):

```
public static Task<IBulkResponse> IndexManyAsync<T>(this IElasticClient client, 
                                                    IEnumerable<T> objects, 
                                                    string index = null, 
                                                    string type = null) where T : class
{
    // <snip>
}
```

[You cannot use Moq to mock extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562129/1698557).