# Unable to MOCK DbSet correctly to test update functionality on underlying entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nunit, moq

I am writing unit tests to test Save DbSet changes. Code looks like:

**PreSchoolContext**

```
DbSet<Student> Students{get;set;}
```

**PreSchoolRepository**

**EDIT**: PreSchoolContext is now a IPreSchoolContext instance, handled thru dependency Injection.

```
public async Task<int> UpdatePreSchoolStudentAsync(Student student)
{   
    PreSchoolContext.Set<Student>().AddOrUpdate(student);
    var result = await PreSchoolContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;              
}
```

**Test Method**

```
//Arrange
var data = GetStudents().AsQueryable();
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Student>>();
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Student>(data.Provider));
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);

var preSchoolContextMock = new Mock<IPreSchoolContext>();
preSchoolContextMock.Setup(c => c.Students).Returns(mockSet.Object);

var repo = new PreSchoolRepository(preSchoolContextMock.Object);

//Act
var preSchoolStudentUpdateFlag = await repo.UpdatePreSchoolStudentAsync(data.FirstOrDefault());

//Assert
preSchoolStudentUpdateFlag.ShouldNotBeNull();
preSchoolStudentUpdateFlag.ShouldBe(1);
```

**Error**

> Unable to call public, instance method AddOrUpdate on derived IDbSet type 'Castle.Proxies.DbSet`1Proxy'. Method not found.

Unable to understand what is missing to set the mock data correctly.

Comment: Why do we insist on try to test code we have no control over. MS would have tested their code before releasing it. That said, your method under test it too tightly coupled to make testing it in isolation not serve any meaningful purpose.

Comment: Issue is your class under test is using a real `PreSchoolContext`, by `new`ing it. You need to have some kind of dependency injection in order to mock the dbcontext

Comment: @AndrewP, updated code. Handling thru dependency injection.

Comment: @Nkosi, I understand, however I was able to test DbSet based select /get methods which is under repositories, however unable to test Update methods of repository due to these issues. Due to this, my unit test coverage % less.

Comment: @AviKenjale what problems are you still encountering after the edit

Comment: @Nkosi, I am using method `PreSchoolContext.Set<Student>().AddOrUpdate(student);`. I mocked `context, DbSet`, and also setup method `Set<Student>()` on context, however, now unit test execution unable to find `AddOrUpdate(params Student[])` somewhere under mocked DbSet. I tried to set it up, however due to signature I cannot.

Comment: @AviKenjale, That method is most likely an extension method. You would need to find the source to know exactly what the method does so that you know what to mock.

Comment: @AviKenjale otherwise you are better or manually copying over the properties that you want to update.

Comment: @AviKenjale That error message confirms that it is an extension method. Moq cannot mock extension methods.

Comment: @Nkosi, sorry, but is there any way to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I Did Some changes to design to test `DbSet<>` **Update** functionality:

Added following function under my context class:

```
public virtual void AddOrUpdateEntity<TEntity>(IProMetrixContext db, 
TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class
{
     db.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entities);
}
```

and then slightly changed `UpdatePreSchoolStudentAsync(Student student)` method as:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateProMetrixRiskAsync(Student student)
{
        PreSchoolContext.AddOrUpdateEntity<Student>(PreSchoolContext, student); //This one resolved issue of unit test and works fine in real scenario too.
        var result = await PreSchoolContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
}
```

Got reference here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37359646/659538)

**NOTE**: If anyone has suggestions on same, please post.