# How do you mock ILogger LogInformation

Tags: c#, logging, mocking

I have a class that receives an ILogger and I want to mock the LogInformation calls but this is an extension method. How do I make the appropiate setup call for this?

Comment: Are you using any specific mocking tool?

Comment: Look at [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs) for these extensions.  All the extensions eventually just call `ILogger.Log()` so if you implement / mock that you are good.

Comment: Extension methods are static and not easily mocked. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq. It sounds like total oversight on the original ILogger design to need an extension for Loginformation Imo.

Comment: If it is a extension, it will probably extend a specific class (Your class that implements Ilogger). You can create a Fake of that class and use it with the extension, to achieve the asserts you expect. You can even create "Fake" results of your class calls. Do a quick google research about C# Mocking frameworks, for example  http://fakeiteasy.github.io/;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unit test with ILogger in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424095/how-to-unit-test-with-ilogger-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 58):

If you're using Moq >= 4.13, here is a way to mock `ILogger`:

```cs
logger.Verify(x => x.Log(
    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()));
```

You can change the `It.IsAny<LogLevel>()`, `It.IsAny<EventId>()`, and `It.IsAny<Exception>()` stubs to be more specific, but using `It.IsAnyType` is necessary because `FormattedLogValues` is now `internal`.

Reference: [TState in ILogger.Log used to be object, now FormattedLogValues](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1319#issuecomment-539521727)

Comment: My kingdom if you also show the .Callback for a Setup !!

Comment: Not working :: .Callback((Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId eventId, object t, Exception ex, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter) =>
                    {

Comment: @ScottFraley I think you have the wrong signature. If you F12 / Go To Definition on ILogger, you do see a Log method that takes the parameter structure crgolden outlines.

Comment: Also `It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()` would work instead of `(Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()`

Comment: I found this solution: https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/mocking-ilogger-with-moq. It describes a Moq only solution also verifying the message. `loggerMock
  .Verify(l => l.Log(
    It.Is<LogLevel>(l => l == LogLevel.Information),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => v.ToString() == "Message"),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()), 
    Times.AtLeastOnce);`

Comment: @MarcelMelzig the best answer so far

Answer (score 36):

Example with a Callback, tested with Moq 4.14.5. More Informations available on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918)

> PM> install-package Moq

```
var logger = new Mock<ILogger<ReplaceWithYourObject>>();

logger.Setup(x => x.Log(
    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Callback(new InvocationAction(invocation =>
    {
        var logLevel = (LogLevel)invocation.Arguments[0]; // The first two will always be whatever is specified in the setup above
        var eventId = (EventId)invocation.Arguments[1];  // so I'm not sure you would ever want to actually use them
        var state = invocation.Arguments[2];
        var exception = (Exception)invocation.Arguments[3];
        var formatter = invocation.Arguments[4];

        var invokeMethod = formatter.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");
        var logMessage = (string)invokeMethod?.Invoke(formatter, new[] { state, exception });
    }));
```

A complete generic helper class for UnitTesting

```
public static class LoggerHelper
{
    public static Mock<ILogger<T>> GetLogger<T>()
    {
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger<T>>();

        logger.Setup(x => x.Log(
            It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Callback(new InvocationAction(invocation =>
            {
                var logLevel = (LogLevel)invocation.Arguments[0]; // The first two will always be whatever is specified in the setup above
                var eventId = (EventId)invocation.Arguments[1];  // so I'm not sure you would ever want to actually use them
                var state = invocation.Arguments[2];
                var exception = (Exception)invocation.Arguments[3];
                var formatter = invocation.Arguments[4];

                var invokeMethod = formatter.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");
                var logMessage = (string)invokeMethod?.Invoke(formatter, new[] { state, exception });

                Trace.WriteLine($"{logLevel} - {logMessage}");
            }));

        return logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: great post - https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/mocking-ilogger-with-moq

Comment: It's a very ingenious solution, btw I'm facing a problem when trying to do structured logging; the `logMessage` unfortunately fails to create a correctly formatted string when passing a parameter a complex object.
It prints only the namespace of the object like "the value is Project.Domain.MyClass"

Answer (score 13):

ILogger is normally used thru extension methods, LogWarning, LogError, etc.

In my case I was interested in the LogWarning method which after looking at the code calls the Log method from ILogger.
In order to mock it with Moq, this is what I ended up doing:

```
     var list = new List<string>();
                var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
                logger
                    .Setup(l => l.Log<FormattedLogValues>(LogLevel.Warning, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<FormattedLogValues>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>>()))
                    .Callback(
                    delegate (LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, FormattedLogValues state, Exception exception, Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string> formatter)
                    {
                        list.Add(state.ToString());
                    });
```

In newer versions of .NET Core 3.0 this won't work. Because FormattedLogValues is an internal type.
You need to update the moq version to at least:

```
`<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.16.0" />`
```

After updating `Moq` The workaround is like this:

```
            var log = new List<string>();
            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
            mockLogger.Setup(
                l => l.Log(
                    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()))
                .Callback((IInvocation invocation) =>
                {
                    var logLevel = (LogLevel)invocation.Arguments[0];
                    var eventId = (EventId)invocation.Arguments[1];
                    var state = (IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)invocation.Arguments[2];
                    var exception = invocation.Arguments[3] as Exception;
                    var formatter = invocation.Arguments[4] as Delegate;
                    var formatterStr = formatter.DynamicInvoke(state, exception);
                    log.Add(
                      $"{logLevel} - {eventId.Id} - Testing - {formatterStr}");
                });
```

Notice the special cast: `(Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>())` and also the IInvocation to handle the arguments.

Comment: I used dependency Injection _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();

Comment: you define global private Mock<ILogger> _logger then in the constructor assign it and in the class where ever call like you display in the code

Comment: Oh man.  I really wanted this to work.   Maybe it is my version.. but I now get : "FormattedLogValues is inaccessible due to its protection level"  :(  This is my sad face.  FYI I have  "    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />"  Maybe consider posting your version of Moq if you get a chance (to maybe see where the cutoff is)  Thanks.

Comment: @granaCoder better late than never. I have updated my code. That works with the moq 4.18

Answer (score 12):

This is a case where a "fake" class may be easier than Moq. It's a little more work to create, but then you can re-use it forever and it's easier to read and work with than a Moq callback. (I like Moq, but not when there's an easier way.)

For most use cases this will work as-is, or you can tweak it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class FakeLogger<T> : ILogger, ILogger<T>
{
    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; } = new List<LogEntry>();

    public IEnumerable<LogEntry> InformationEntries =>
        LogEntries.Where(e => e.LogLevel == LogLevel.Information);

    public IEnumerable<LogEntry> WarningEntries =>
        LogEntries.Where(e => e.LogLevel == LogLevel.Warning);

    public IEnumerable<LogEntry> ErrorEntries =>
        LogEntries.Where(e => e.LogLevel == LogLevel.Error);

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry(logLevel, eventId, state, exception));
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new LoggingScope();
    }

    public class LoggingScope : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}

public class LogEntry
{
    public LogEntry(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, object state, Exception exception)
    {
        LogLevel = logLevel;
        EventId = eventId;
        State = state;
        Exception = exception;
    }

    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; }
    public EventId EventId { get; }
    public object State { get; }
    public Exception Exception { get; }
    public string Message => State?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    public Dictionary<string, object> Params => (State as IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object?>>)!.ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Value)!;
    public string FormatString => (string)Params["{OriginalFormat}"];
}
```

Create an instance and inject it into your test class as the logger. Then you can look at the objects in the `LogEntries` collection to see what got logged.

The type of `State` will typically be `FormattedLogValues`, but you can call `State.ToString()` and just get the string value.

Comment: Easiest way, honestly. Tried a few others listed here, had issues with them. It's easy to forget that sometimes a fake is better than a mock. Smart thinking.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where I end up searching for my own answer and pasting the code over and over.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a `logger` (`new Mock<ILogger<ReplaceWithYourObject>>()`) mock injected in ctor. Then this should help to verify log message and log level.

```
logger.Verify(x => x.Log(
       LogLevel.Information, //Change LogLevel as required
       It.IsAny<EventId>(),
       It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((object v, Type _) => 
       v.ToString().Contains("MessageToVerify")), // Change MessageToVerify as required
       It.IsAny<Exception>(),
       (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()));
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I workaround for **Moq** (v4.10.1) framework.

```
public static class TestHelper
{ 

    public static Mock<ILogger<T>> GetMockedLoggerWithAutoSetup<T>()
    {
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger<T>>();

        logger.Setup<object>(x => x.Log(
       It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
       It.IsAny<EventId>(),
       It.IsAny<object>(),
       It.IsAny<Exception>(),
       It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()));

        return logger;
    }

    public static void VerifyLogMessage<T>(Mock<ILogger<T>> mockedLogger, LogLevel logLevel, Func<string, bool> predicate, Func<Times> times)
    {
        mockedLogger.Verify(x => x.Log(logLevel, 0, It.Is<object>(p => predicate(p.ToString())), null, It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()), times);
    }
}
```

--

```
public class Dummy
{

}

[Fact]
public void Should_Mock_Logger()
{
    var logger = TestHelper.GetMockedLoggerWithAutoSetup<Dummy>();
    logger.Object.LogInformation("test");
    TestHelper.VerifyLogMessage<Dummy>(logger, LogLevel.Information, msg => msg == "test", Times.Once);
}
```

--

The thing is,

If I had chosen any other `<TCustom>` than `<object>` for `logger.Setup()`, it would fail on `Verify` step saying that **0 calls** were made for `x.Log<TCustom>` and showing a call made to `x.Log<object>`. So I setup my generic logger to mock `Log<object>(..)` method instead.

Comment: Hu, seems to have broken recently

Answer (score 1):

Was greatly helped by @live2's answer above. Just completed it by making it into a
class that can be used for verifications;

```
public class MockedLogger<T>
{
    public MockedLogger()
    {
        Mock = new Mock<ILogger<T>>();
        Mock.Setup(x => x.Log(
                It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Callback(new InvocationAction(invocation =>
            {
                var logLevel = (LogLevel)invocation.Arguments[0];
                var eventId = (EventId)invocation.Arguments[1];
                var state = invocation.Arguments[2];
                var exception = (Exception)invocation.Arguments[3];
                var formatter = invocation.Arguments[4];

                var invokeMethod = formatter.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");
                var logMessage = (string)invokeMethod?.Invoke(formatter, new[] { state, exception });

                LoggedMessages.Add((logLevel, logMessage));
            }));
    }

    public Mock<ILogger<T>> Mock { get; }
    public List<(LogLevel Level, string Message)> LoggedMessages { get; } = new List<(LogLevel Level, string Message)>();
}
```

Usage in unit test (`NUnit` with `FluentAssertions`);

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_doing_something
{
    private readonly MockedLogger<ClassUnderTest> _mockedLogger = new MockedLogger<ClassUnderTest>();

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        await new ClassUnderTest(_mockedLogger.Mock.Object).DoSomething();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_the_operation_is_logged()
    {
        _mockedLogger.LoggedMessages.Should().Contain((LogLevel.Information, "expected log message"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing lots of very heavy solutions here, so I will share my very lightweight approach.

Normally, I just want to verify that when something was called, it should log x many times.  So in my unit tests I just make a new implementaion of `Logger<T>` and use the facade pattern to expose a public field which I can then use for testing.

```
private class VerifiableLogger : ILogger<T>//Replace T with your type
{
    public int calledCount { get; set; }

    //boiler plate, required to implement ILogger<T>
    IDisposable ILogger.BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    bool ILogger.IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    //Meaningful method, this get's called when you use .LogInformation()
    void ILogger.Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter) 
      =>  this.calledCount++;
}
```

If you wanted to check and see what the last log message was, or to see all of the log messages, you could use this similar approach I've also used.

```
private class VerifiableLogger : ILogger<T>
        {
            public int calledCount { get; set; }
            public List<string> logList { get; set; }

            IDisposable ILogger.BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => throw new NotImplementedException();
            bool ILogger.IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => throw new NotImplementedException();
            void ILogger.Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter) {
                this.calledCount++;
                if (state != null)
                {
                    this.logList.Add(state.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can dig into the results in your unit tests.  Very good to verify formatting for structured logging purposes, if you wanted to do so.

[image]