# How to mock ILogger.LogXXX methods on netcore 3.0

Tags: moq, .net-core-3.0, ilogger

Until now, we I was mocking the `ILogger.LogXXX` calls by following this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707702/how-do-you-mock-ilogger-loginformation/52713598).

Unfortunately, after updating the project to .net core 3.0, and if you're using strict mocks (Moq), it will always complain about not having a corresponding setup:

```
Moq.MockException : ILogger.Log<FormattedLogValues>(LogLevel.Information, 0, 
           Inicio de cancelamento de reserva:  Grm.GestaoFrotas.Dtos.Reservas.Mensagens.MsgCancelamentoReserva, 
           null, 
           Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.
```

Unfortunately, I can't simple change object with `FormattedLogValues` like this:

```
_container.GetMock<ILogger<GestorReservas>>()
          .Setup(l => l.Log(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                            It.IsAny<FormattedLogValues>(),
                            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                            It.IsAny<Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>()));
```

This won't work because `FormattedLogValues` is internal.

I can always change the mocking strategy (strict to loose), but I'd prefer to keep it as it is (strict). So, any clues on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From version 4.13 you could use `It.IsAnyType`...

Comment: @Johnny could you post an example? I had the same issue, tried replacing `FormattedLogValues` with `It.IsAnyAtype` and now I'm getting another error:

Comment: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart, find matching generic type arguments...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
//    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
//    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />

container.GetMock<ILogger<GestorReservas>>()
          .Setup(l => l.Log(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
                            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>())));
```

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/79804378-cannot-verify-calls-to-ilogger-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8-generic-type-matcher-doesn-t-work-with-verify

Comment: Please give some explanation of your solution rather than only code.

Comment: This does in fact fix the issue, but how? The key part is casting Any<object> as a formatter Func. That seems like an error, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

This expands on Muk's answer.

My addition is "ILoggerFactory"..and how you "code up" the actually logging inside your real class.

First, unit test code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;


    private Mock<ILoggerFactory> GetDefaultILoggerFactoryMock()
    {
        Mock<ILoggerFactory> returnMock = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>(MockBehavior.Loose);
        returnMock.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(
            () =>
                this.GetDefaultILoggerMock<MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor>().Object);
        return returnMock;
    }

    private Mock<ILogger<T>> GetDefaultILoggerMock<T>()
    {
        Mock<ILogger<T>> returnMock = new Mock<ILogger<T>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        returnMock.Setup(
            m => m.Log(
                It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                It.IsAny<object>(),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())).Callback(
            (LogLevel ll, EventId eid, object obj1, Exception ex, Func<object, Exception, string> func) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(func.Invoke(obj1, ex));
            }).Verifiable();
        returnMock.Setup(m => m.IsEnabled(It.IsAny<LogLevel>())).Returns(false);
        return returnMock;
    }
```

Now, in your actual class (here I call it 'MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor')..you need to use the NON EXTENSION METHOD of making log calls.  (All the helper methods like LogInformation are static extension methods overloads)

So like this:
(I am using very "wordy" values to clarify what is what (a log-msg/"state" vs what the formatter does). (Your code probably won't be "wordy" like mine).

```
        string logMsgAkaTheState = "Here_Is_The_Log_Message_Aka_The_StateArgument";
        Func<object, Exception, string> formatterFunc = (theObj, theException) => "*formatter-start*" + theObj + "*formatter-middle*" + (null == theException ? "theExceptionIsNull" : theException.Message)  + "*formatter-end*";
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, ushort.MaxValue, logMsgAkaTheState, null, formatterFunc);
```

or for one that is an exception

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string logMsgAkaTheState = "Here_Is_Another_Log_Message_Aka_The_StateArgument";
            Func<object, Exception, string> errorFormatterFunc = (theObj, theException) => "*formatter-start*" + theObj + "*formatter-middle*" + (null == theException ? "theExceptionIsNull" : theException.Message)  + "*formatter-end*";

            this.logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ushort.MaxValue, null, ex, errorFormatterFunc);
        }
```

If you do both of those things, especially the second part, you can Mock the ILoggerFactory / ILogger

Here is the germane parts of the class/constructor:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor : IMyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor
{
    public const string ErrorMsgILoggerFactoryIsNull = "ILoggerFactory is null";

    private readonly ILogger<MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor> logger;
    

    public MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (null == loggerFactory)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMsgILoggerFactoryIsNull, (Exception)null);
        }

        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyConcreteClassThatUsesILoggerFactoryInItsConstructor>();

    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {

        string logMsgAkaTheState = "Here_Is_The_Log_Message_Aka_The_StateArgument";
        Func<object, Exception, string> formatterFunc = (theObj, theException) => "*formatter-start*" + theObj + "*formatter-middle*" + (null == theException ? "theExceptionIsNull" : theException.Message)  + "*formatter-end*";
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, ushort.MaxValue, logMsgAkaTheState, null, formatterFunc);

        int div = 0;

        try
        {
            int x = 1 / div;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string logMsgAkaTheState = "Here_Is_Another_The_Log_Message_Aka_The_StateArgument";
        Func<object, Exception, string> errorFormatterFunc = (theObj, theException) => "*formatter-start*" + theObj + "*formatter-middle*" + (null == theException ? "theExceptionIsNull" : theException.Message)  + "*formatter-end*";
        
            this.logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ushort.MaxValue, null, ex, errorFormatterFunc);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/mocking-ilogger-with-moq describes it with a Moq only solution.

```
loggerMock
  .Verify(l => l.Log(
    It.Is<LogLevel>(l => l == LogLevel.Information),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => v.ToString() == "Message"),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()), 
    Times.AtLeastOnce);
```