# Mock extension methods IElasticClient

Tags: c#, .net, moq, dotcover

Is there a way to mock the following

```
        var result = await Client.SearchAsync<IndexedSite>(d => d
            .Index(SiteIndexName)
            .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
            .Sort(sd => sd.Field(s => s.Name, SortOrder.Ascending))
            .Take(c_maxSiteListSize));
```

Would one use .Callbacks in this situation?

My current setup:

```
    private Mock<IElasticClient> _client = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
    private Mock<ISearchResponse<IndexedSite>> indexedSite = new Mock<ISearchResponse<IndexedSite>>();

    _client.Setup(x =>
        x.SearchAsync<IndexedSite>(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<IndexedSite>, ISearchRequest>>(),
            default(CancellationToken))).Returns(Task.FromResult(indexedSite.Object));
```

This works, and it does return indexedSite, however it does not 'Cover' .Index/.Query/.Sort/.Take extension methods, which is what I want.

Comment: No, it is not possible to Mock extension methods. You need to refactor and get rid of extension methods in order to make it testable

Comment: Also, you can use `.ReturnAsync` instead of `.Returns(Task.FromResult(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Olegl answer. It is not possible to Mock extension methods. You need to refactor and get rid of extension methods in order to make it testable

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562129/how-do-i-use-moq-to-mock-an-extension-method)