# Problem mocking MassTransit method for testing

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, masstransit

I'm writing a test for a Consumer using masstransit.

```
var _context = new Mock<ConsumeContext<AcionaMessageCommand>>(); 
    _context.Setup(x => x.GetRedeliveryCount()).Returns(1);
```

when running it is returning error:

> Unsupported expression: x => x.GetRedeliveryCount()
> Extension methods (here: RetryContextExtensions.GetRedeliveryCount) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Could anyone tell me a way to mock this method, or another way to do this?

I tried to make a mock using:

```
_context.Setup(x => x.Headers.Get<int>("MT-Redelivery-Count")).Returns(1);
```

But in this case it always returns zero

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562129/how-do-i-use-moq-to-mock-an-extension-method

Comment: Consider reviewing the docs here https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html